# Porting old Code to Cocos2d-x rc0 2.1.3 giving error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cocos2d-x

I have an old code. I am porting it to new Cocos2d-x rc0 2.1.3 .It is giving me errors in following lines:

1.
in GameScene.cpp

```
CCScene *scene = CCScene::node();
GameScene *layer = GameScene::node();
```

2.
in GameScene.cpp

```
userPaddle_->runAction(CCMoveTo::actionWithDuration(0.3 * diffX / gameArea_.size.width, destPosition));
```

3.
in GameScene.cpp

```
CCPoint location = touch->locationInView(touch->view());
```

4.
in GameScene.cpp

```
if (CCRect::CCRectContainsPoint(touchArea_, location))
```

5.
in GameScene.cpp

```
if (CCRect::CCRectIntersectsRect(ballRect, CC_SPRITE_RECT(paddle)))
```

6.
in Appdelegate.cpp

```
pDirector->setOpenGLView(&CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView());
```

7.
in GameScene.h

```
// implement the "static node()" method manually
LAYER_NODE_FUNC(HelloWorld);
```

Comment: i think it will help if you can post the error message.

Comment: m.ding reply worked can you please tell 6th error.

Comment: try this `pDirector->setOpenGLView(CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView())` ?

Comment: this works Now new error pops up [Link](http://i.imgur.com/0R4cPNm.jpg) JIT must be enabled . Though mine is enabled under tools->debugging->Just in Time.

Comment: This means the frame is Null, which you might trying to create a sprite from a png file not exist (or at least not exist on the path you specified)

Comment: It is coming in the line userPaddle_ = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("square.png"); square.png is in the resource folder.

Comment: thanks,I figure it out it should be CCSprite::create("square.png");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the full list of cocos2d-x API changes, please refer to

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/API_Change_List_from_v1x_to_2x

and

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/About_Static_Constructor_API_changes_in_cocos2d-x_v20

`node()` -> `create()`

`actionWithDuation(a,b)` -> `create(a,b)`

`CCRect::CCRectContainsPoint(touchArea_, location)` -> `touchArea_.containsPoint(location)`

`touch->locationInView(touch->view())` -> `touch->getLocation()`

`CCRect::CCRectIntersectsRect(ballRect, CC_SPRITE_RECT(paddle))` - > `ballRect.intersectsRect(CC_SPRITE_RECT(paddle))`

`LAYER_NODE_FUNC` -> `CREATE_FUNC` if still exist.

I forgot the OpenGLView one, but there is one.